# match url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this. And using this to match the a string from the url and fire the jquery to hide a generated div. what am I doing wrong? When I am passing an alert instead of .hide() its firing.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("HairTransformation-Press") > -1) {
        $('.product').hide();
    }
```

Here is the updated code

```
$(window).load(function (){
    var myString = "HairTransformation-Press";

if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(myString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $('.product').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: you should convert toLowerCase() both strings, in order to do good comparison

Comment: Does an element with a class of `product` exist?

Comment: if your div element has a unique ID, your could do: document.getElementById('.product').style.visibility='hidden'

Comment: document.getElementById('.product') <- this is invalid javascript. If you want to select the element by its id you use getElementById ( %ID_OF_ELEMENT ). If you want to select from its class use getElementsByClassName( %CLASS_OF_ELEMENT )

Comment: sorry..it was totally my bad..i grabbed the wrong version. I corrected it now. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myString = "HairTransformation-Press";

if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(myString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $('.product').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Element with classname `"product"`? if yes, then I think your script is executing before actually the DOM is loaded.

Comment: answering to your question yes I do have a class called product. So probably i can run a window load function to avoid the scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think the matching is not the problem, as your alert is being shown. maybe you're using wrong class name (.product is maybe your ID and should be #product) or did not place the reference to your .js file before the reference to the jquery lib in your html file.

install firebug if you're using firefox or any other dev tool suitable for your browser and check the error log of the javascript console.

Comment: I am wondering now does this have anything to do with the version of jquery? I am using 1.3.2..does that have to do anything with this?

Comment: i dont think so. make sure you're executing your code in the .ready event (http://api.jquery.com/ready/). to see if jquery is actually loaded when you are executing the call use something like this: alert(jQuery); to check if jquery is loaded.

Comment: @larry: yeah..that is what is confusing me. I am using .ready()...and its firing an alert but is not able to affect any div

Comment: sounds weird. when jquery is loaded and you are using the .ready event you should be able to access the object IF you're using **the proper class name**. place a call to `alert($('.product').length);` in your event. this should display a number bigger than 0. to make sure jquery works properly use a call to `alert($('body').length);` if your html file has a body tag it should definitly return 1.